# "Cannot install application" error while running app on Tizen Studio

Tags: tizen, galaxy, tizen-studio

I have trouble connecting with Tizen Studio. I am trying to begin with this environment but am unable to run an app in `debug mode` using my Samsung Galaxy Watch.

I followed online tutorials but get the following error:

`"Cannot install application. Operation not allowed [-4]"`

I have created a Certificate with both an Author and Distributor and added UID of my Galaxy Watch numerous times. I also reinstalled "Tizen Certificate Manager" however I get the following message:
`"There is no generated certificate profile".`

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czQPR.jpg) of the Tizen Certificate Manager.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All the troubles were connected with the operating system which was Windows 10, after installing Tizen Studio with certificate manager on Windows 7 (virtual machine) everything worked at first try.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that while you did indeed create a Certificate for the device you didn't actually uploaded it to it.

Procedure is slightly different depending on the Tizen Studio version, but in the latest one they moved the whole thing to the [Device Manager](https://developer.tizen.org/development/visual-studio-tools-tizen/tools/device-manager) (*has to be launched separately*).

[image]

You need to connect the device, pop the context menu up with a right click on it and select **Permit to install applications**.

Certificate will be uploaded to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, apparently that was because I tried to install Tizen 5.0 which was not compatible with the wearable I tried to install on (should have opened a Tizen 4.0 project in visual studio).

After that I was able to install by running:

```
$ sdb install <path-to-tpk>.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable-1.0.0.tpk
```

See this example:

```
C:\tizenSdk\tools>sdb install C:\Users\aviad\source\repos\SensiboTizenWearable\SensiboTizenWearable\bin\Debug\tizen40\org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable-1.0.0.tpk
WARNING: Your data are to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could be read by others.
pushed org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable-1.0.0.tpk 100%        618KB           0KB/s
1 file(s) pushed. 0 file(s) skipped.
C:\Users\aviad\source\repos\SensiboTizenWearable\SensiboTizenWearable\bin\Debug\tizen40\org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable-1.0.0.tpk   967KB/s (633407 bytes in 0.639s)
path is /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable-1.0.0.tpk
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[start] val[install]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[9]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[12]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[15]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[18]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[21]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[25]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[28]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[31]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[34]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[37]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[40]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[43]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[46]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[50]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[53]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[56]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[59]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[62]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[65]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[68]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[71]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[75]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[78]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[81]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[84]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[87]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[90]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[93]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[96]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[install_percent] val[100]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[tpk] pkgid[org.tizen.example.SensiboTizenWearable] key[end] val[ok]
spend time for pkgcmd is [27655]ms
```

Comment: what wearable do you have?